# Wrong vertical align of text in Chrome Mobile browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, vertical-alignment

I have a div with fixed height containing some text. line-height = height of the div. Problem: in Chrome Mobile the text doesn't perfectly center vertically. In Firefox Mobile all is ok. Please note that I'm using standard Verdana font.

I discovered also some other websites suffer from the same problem.

How can I fix this problem, any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Add the following flex CSS style properties to your particular div container and it should be okay.

```css
.cells-block {
  font-family: Verdana;
  width:300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* vertically   */
  justify-content: center;
  /* horisontally */
  text-align: center;
  /* addition: for text's lines */
}
```

```html
<div class="cells-block">
  This is some text<br>Randomrandom stuff
</div>
```